# How to make server recompile code behind files

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm using Asp.net 4 and IIS 7. I have a remote desktop connection to the server, and I am rebuilding my solution in visual studio and then replacing the new code behind file on my local computer with that of the web servers deployed version.

However it is not recompiling and using my updated file. I've tried stopping the server, recycling the app pool, replacing files in the app_code, bin directory, and searching with no luck. For now the files are not dll's.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete the compiled assemblies from the `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v.xxxx\Temporary ASP.NET 
Files\<site name>` directory.

This is where IIS generates the assemblies - deleting these should cause it to recompile.

Comment: If I delete that folder and access the web site it does recreate that folder, but for instance the default.aspx and it's new code behind on the root is not being reflected.

Comment: @Nick - did you recycle the application?

Comment: @Oded, I did recycle it, Here's what I did. Stopped the app pool > delete folder > recycle app > ran web site.

Comment: @Nick - is this a precompiled site?

Comment: @Oded, I'm not sure, how would I find out? ... Does precompiled mean all files are in dll's before going to the server?

Comment: @Nick - Yes, apart from the `.aspx`, javascript, css and other static content. There would be a `<sitename>.dll` in the bin directory.

Comment: Inside the Temporary ASP.NET Files there is a folder called root that i'm deleting. No site name.

Comment: @Nick - I am talking about the website bin directory.

Comment: @Oded, yes there is one there.

Comment: @Nick - That means that all the code behind gets complied to that DLL. You need to deploy that to your webserver bin directory to see the changes.

Comment: @Oded, I see, I also realized that the web.config isn't inside, I still have to change it seperately, got it working though. Thanks for sticking it out through the end.

Comment: @Nick - no problem. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: @Oded, So technically the deployed site in my case should not have any codebehind or .cs files anywhere as they are in that .dll? I should just have webforms and js/css files?

Comment: @Nick - That's right. If you use the website _publish_ mechanism in Visual Studio, all of this is taken care of.

Comment: @Oded, I'm assuming I need to choose the option that says only deploy necesarry files to run this application? I'm not able to publish directly to the server via visual studio. I have to remote desktop and drag the files from my shared drive. There may be a way to do it, but I don't know how.

Comment: @Nick - correct. You _can_ publish to a local directory and upload that.